# Ubuntu on Sony tablet S

Tags: installation, sony

As a Ubuntu user in my home/work I want to install it on my tablet. The tablet is a Sony tablet S, but I didn't found trustable info anywere. It is possible to install Ubuntu on Sony tablet S? If it is, how can I do it?

Thanks,

Diego

Answer (score 1):

I guess no, because sony tablet s has nvidia tegra 3 chip and the recent UBUNTU ROMs are suitable only for ARM Cortex A7 processors.